# Grafana pod keeps restarting after helm install

Tags: kubernetes, grafana, kubernetes-helm, azure-aks, prometheus-operator

I have a clean AKS cluster that I deployed the prometheus-operator chart.  The Grafana pod is showing a ton of restarts.  My cluster version is 1.11.3.  Grafana logs below.  Anyone else encounter this issue?

```
File in configmap grafana-dashboard-k8s-node-rsrc-use.json ADDED
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/response.py", line 543, in _update_chunk_length
    self.chunk_left = int(line, 16)
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 16: b''
 During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
 Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/response.py", line 302, in _error_catcher
    yield
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/response.py", line 598, in read_chunked
    self._update_chunk_length()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/response.py", line 547, in _update_chunk_length
    raise httplib.IncompleteRead(line)
http.client.IncompleteRead: IncompleteRead(0 bytes read)
 During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
 Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/app/sidecar.py", line 58, in &lt;module&gt;
    main()
  File "/app/sidecar.py", line 54, in main
    watchForChanges(label, targetFolder)
  File "/app/sidecar.py", line 23, in watchForChanges
    for event in w.stream(v1.list_config_map_for_all_namespaces):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/kubernetes/watch/watch.py", line 124, in stream
    for line in iter_resp_lines(resp):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/kubernetes/watch/watch.py", line 45, in iter_resp_lines
    for seg in resp.read_chunked(decode_content=False):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/response.py", line 626, in read_chunked
    self._original_response.close()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/contextlib.py", line 99, in __exit__
    self.gen.throw(type, value, traceback)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/response.py", line 320, in _error_catcher
    raise ProtocolError('Connection broken: %r' % e, e)
urllib3.exceptions.ProtocolError: ('Connection broken: IncompleteRead(0 bytes read)', IncompleteRead(0 bytes read))
```

Comment: Looks like you have a python sidecar. Do you have the deployment/pod definition for grafana?

Comment: Yes, there are three containers in the pod.

kiwigrid/k8s-sidecar:0.0.3
kiwigrid/k8s-sidecar:0.0.3
grafana/grafana:5.3.1

Comment: What did you use to install this? the guide I followed doesn't have sidecars

Comment: helm install stable/prometheus-operator

Answer (score 0):

Based on the [Prometheus operator repository](https://github.com/coreos/prometheus-operator/blob/master/helm/grafana/templates/grafana-deployment.yaml#L69)... The sidecar container on the Grafana pod is failing to contact Grafana and reload/refresh the dashboards defined on the configmap being watched.

So the this is a symptom of the Grafana container failing... can you check Grafana container inside your Grafana pod logs?

Comment: The logs for the Grafana container appear normal and I am able to view the dashboards in a browser.  The pod restarts have also leveled out.  There were 280 in the first 12 hours or so and none since.
The dashboard appears to be working, but it is a bit troubling that I am still seeing failures in the logs for the sidecar containers as in the original question.

Answer (score 0):

This can be fixed by updating to a more recent version of the side-car container since it's a known bug there that got fixed